# How To Update XML File On Radio button Click (Client Side) C# Web Application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have created xml file with the code shown below,

```
  XElement xml = new XElement("Configuration",
                new XElement("Config",
                new XElement("Link", Link.Text),
                new XElement("CostPerUnit", txtCommission.Text),
                new XElement("Ischart", Ischart)
                )
                );
                xml.Save(@"c:\ConfigurationFile.xml");
```

i want to update its Ischart value it is of string type and gets only true and false  value when i click power radio button it update this xml file and change only Ischart =true or when i click Cost radio button it update this xml file and change only Ischart =false i want to do it on client side 
   Hopes for your Suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use AJAX to communicate from client to server.. 
check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/